# Proof of identity involving binomial coefficient

Tags: analysis, binomial-coefficients

My homework assignment was essentially to prove the following *binomial coefficient identity*:

> Prove
>   $$\begin{pmatrix} -n \\ k\end{pmatrix} = (-1)^k \begin{pmatrix} n+k-1 \\ k\end{pmatrix}$$

Using the definition $\begin{pmatrix} n \\ k\end{pmatrix} := \prod_{j=1}^k \frac{n+1-j}{j}$ I get

$$\prod_{j=1}^k \frac{-n+1-j}{j} = (-1)^k \prod_{j=1}^k \frac{n+k-1+1-j}{j}$$

Which is equivalent to

$$\prod_{j=1}^k -n+1-j = \prod_{j=1}^k -n-k+j$$

Now the $1-j$ in the first term and the $-k+j$ in the second term create the same set, but in the opposite direction: $1-j$ goes from $0$ to $1-k$, while $-k+j$ goes from $1-k$ to $0$, so both products are the same.

But how do I prove this in a formal way?

Comment: Just a $\LaTeX$ tip: `\binom{n+k-1}{k}` is less typing than `\begin{pmatrix} ... \end{pmatrix}` (and may have better spacing properties, but I don't know if they do differ in that respect).

Comment: Strange question... by definition, if $n<k$ therefore $\binom{n}{k}=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\binom{-n}{k} &= \frac{(-n - k + 1)(-n - k + 2)\cdots (-n)}{k!}\\
& = (-1)^k \frac{(n + k - 1)(n + k - 2)\cdots (n)}{k!} \\
& = (-1)^k \binom{n+k-1}{k}.
\end{align}